# Java DOM XML: Need namespace prefix on namespace but not element name

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I have the following codeblock at the beginning of building an XML in Java.  ROOT_ELEM is obviously the root element.

```
 try{
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.newDocument();

        root = doc.createElementNS(NS,"xsi:" + ROOT_ELEM);
        doc.appendChild(root);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to create an XML document.", e);
    }
```

The `root = doc.createElementNS(NS,"xsi:" + ROOT_ELEM);` part adds the namespace with the xsi prefix for the XML line:

```
<xsi:rootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

My problem is that I need the `xsi` on the `xmlns:xsi=...` part but not on the `xsi:rootElement` part.  Is this possible?  I know I can convert the whole thing to a `String` and do a search and replace but that's hackish and I wanted to know if there is a way to do with methodically with the DOM Parser api. Here is the line I want:

```
<rootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Comment: Without the `xmlns:xsi` attribute, `xsi` is not a valid prefix, which would make your XML invalid.  You can, however, define `xmlns:xsi` on any ancestor element instead of defining it on `rootElement`.

Comment: Right, I want to keep the xmlns:xsi part but the prefix before rootElement, xsi:rootElement, is the part I want to erase.  When I do it manually the XML is valid.

Comment: Then why pass `"xsi:" + ROOT_ELEM`?

Comment: Because that adds the namespace property to that element.  Do you know of a different method I should be using?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13048523/1831987 .